# Clearing a line of a txt file by the line ID

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader, streamwriter

I have looked all over for the answer to this, but I can't find it anywhere. I need to be able to clear a line from a txt file by the last integer in the line (the ID number), but I have no idea how to do that. Please help? Basically I was thinking that I need to find the last integer, and if it does not equal to the input, then it would move to the next line until it finds the right integer. Then that line is cleared. Here is some of my code that obviously doesn't work:

```
public static void TicID(CommandArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Parameters.Count == 1)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    string idToDelete = args.Parameters[0];
                    StreamReader idreader = new StreamReader("Tickets.txt");
                    StreamWriter iddeleter = new StreamWriter("Tickets.txt");
                    string id = Convert.ToString(idreader.Read());
                    string line = null;
                    while (idreader.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        if (String.Compare(id, idToDelete) == 0)
                        {
                            iddeleter.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            idreader.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you know how to read a file? do you know how to manipulate strings? do you know how to write to a file? seems like you've done nothing so far but asking "how", don't expect us to do the work for you. You could *atleast* show us how your data looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that, but I am actually away from my computer right now (doing this on my phone) When I get back I promise to put some of my data and info. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a StreamReader object and read line by line into a string array or something like that using StreamReader's instance method ReadLine() and now find your line of choice in your text array and delete it.

Important note:

```
do { /*see description above*/ } while (streamReader.Peak() != -1);
```

Comment: So basically, I just have a reader go through, store all the info, find the one that is being looked for, and then rewrite all the info. The problem is, I don't know how to work with arrays, but I am currently looking up tutorials to that.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to delete lines is to write the lines that should not be deleted:

```
var idToDelete = "1";
var path = @"C:\Temp\Test.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, false)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        //assuming it's a CSV file
        var cols = line.Split(',');
        var id = cols[cols.Length - 1];
        if (id != idToDelete) {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the LINQ-way:

```
var lines = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
        let cols = line.Split(',')
        let id = cols[cols.Length - 1]
        where id != idToDelete
        select line;
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: Looks good from my phone so far, when I get home I'll try it, if it works I wont bother uploading some of my code to the original question :D thanks for answering :]

Comment: This actually did not work for me :[ sorry :[ There were no errors, but it just didn't do anything.

Comment: @Spectrewiz: It works, but you haven't told use what your data looks like. Is it a CSV file, which separator does it have, have all lines the same count of columns etc.? You can use the debugger to see why my code doesn't find your ID.